# If $f$ is continuous & $\lim_{|x|\to {\infty}}f(x)=0$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous or NOT?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

> Let, $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that $\lim_{|x|\to {\infty}}f(x)=0.$ Then prove or disprove that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

I tried through the formal definition of uniform continuity but I could not proceed further.

Is it directly follow from definition or any other property about continuity to prove this?

Please help....

Comment: $f(x) = 1/x$ is not continuous at $x=0$, regardless of what value you assign at $x=0$.

Comment: See also: [A function vanishing at infinity is uniformly continuous](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/705961)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hint: To show that, first fix $\epsilon >0$, then your assumption imply that there is $M>0$ so that

$$|f(x)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

when $|x| >M$. What can you say about

$$|f(x) - f(y)|$$

when $|x|, |y| >M$? And what about $f$ on $[-(M+1), M+1]$?

Comment: Please give details.

Comment: @Panja.S. : Probably it is better for you to tell which parts of  my answer you think you would have problem with. I am happy to talk about that.

Comment: Great answer, just enough detail to be able to write down a proof : )

Comment: Hoe we show $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta$ ?

Comment: @Panja.S. : Can you show that for $|x|, |y|>M$?

Comment: Yes.I can show it..

Comment: @Panja.S. So how about when $x, y\in [-(M+1), M+1]$? Note that $f$ is uniformly continuous when restricted on this interval.

Comment: How $|x|\le (M+1)$ from $|x|>M$ ?

Comment: @Panja.S. I mean there are two cases. The first case is that $|x|, |y| >M$ and the second case is $|x|, |y|\leq M+1$.

Comment: The second case is clear but the first case???

Comment: @Panja.S. : Note $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq |f(x)| + |f(y)|$.

Answer (score 9):

Define $\phi(x) = \begin{cases} f(\tan x), & |x| < {\pi \over 2} \\
0, & |x|={\pi \over 2} \end{cases}$.
It is easy to see that $\phi:[-{\pi \over 2},{\pi \over 2}] \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous, hence uniformly continuous since $[-{\pi \over 2},{\pi \over 2}]$
is compact.

We have $f(x) = \phi(\arctan x)$, and since $|\arctan'(x)|<1$, we see from the mean value theorem that
$|\arctan x -\arctan y| \le |x-y|$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $\delta>0$ be such that if $|x-y| < \delta$ then $|\phi(x)-\phi(y)| < \epsilon$. Since $|\arctan x -\arctan y|< \delta$, we have
$|f(x)-f(y)| = |\phi(\arctan x) - \phi(\arctan y) | < \epsilon$, and so
$f$ is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Is $\phi(-π/2) = 0$ ?

Comment: @LAMDA: Yes, that is what the first line says.