# Uniform continuity of continuous function $f$ with $\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Suppose that we have a function, $f$, that is continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ and $$\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x) = 0$$
We want to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

So, since $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x) = 0$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists a > 0$ such that $x > a$ implies $|f(x)| < \epsilon$. Since $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = 0$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, $\exists b < 0$ such that $x < b$ implies $|f(x)| < \epsilon$.

So let $\epsilon > 0$. We need to show that $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, if $|x - y| < \delta$, then $|f(x) - f(y)| = \epsilon$.

I got to the point where $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ for all $x, y > N_\epsilon$. But I am having a trouble connecting this fact to "$|x - y| < \delta$".

Also, since this function is not explicitly defined, it is very hard to connect between $|x-y|$ and $|f(x) - f(y)|$. I need some help at this moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $f$ is continuous & $\lim_{|x|\to {\infty}}f(x)=0$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous or NOT?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106275/if-f-is-continuous-lim-x-to-inftyfx-0-then-f-is-uniformly-cont)

Comment: The answer to the possible duplicate does not clarify my understanding of this problem.

Comment: @S.Panja-1729 I know that.

Comment: Dude  just leave me alone with it I am working on the answer with the posted one here.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow: 1) Fix $\varepsilon >0$. 2) From the fact that the limits at $\pm \infty $ are $0$, deduce that outside some interval $[a,b]$, $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon $ (simply since far enough along the $X$-axis the values of $f(x)$ can be made arbitrarily small, in particular smaller than $\varepsilon /2 $). 3) Remember that since $f$ is continuous, it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. 4) Piece things together.

Comment: What $\delta$ would make $|f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon$ on the interval outside $[a, b]$?

Comment: You don't need to know!  You don't need an explicit $\delta$ or even a way to relate it to $\epsilon$ because you know that, as @IttayWeiss says, $f(x)<\epsilon/2$ once $x$ is close enough to either infinity.  So choose both $x$ and $y$ that far out.  They'll be $\delta$ apart (and you don't need to know $\delta$) but $|f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$ by choice of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @postmortes How do we know that this delta does not depend on $x, y$?

Comment: @SeojunHong it probably does, but that doesn't matter.  The definition of uniform continuity requires that $\epsilon$ does not depend on the point $x$ chosen, only on the function $f$.