# Uniform continuity of asymptotically infinitesimal function

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

> **Proposition.** Let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous and such that $\lim_{|x|\to+\infty} f(x) = 0$. Then $f$ is uniformly continuous.

How to prove such a statement?

The hypothesis means that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ I can find an $M > 0$ such that for all $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $|x| > M$ we have $|f(x)| \leq \varepsilon$. If I pick $\varepsilon > 0$ and find such $M$. Then by Heine's theorem $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[-M,+M]$. How do I establish uniform continuity on the rest of the domain?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1106275/219176

Comment: the proof is almost finished, just use the definition of uniform cont.

Comment: Won't the $\delta$ given by the uniform continuity of $f$ on $[-M,+M]$ also work for pairs of points taken outside of this closed interval, but both on the same side? It seemed too easy to close it off like that, so I asked.