# Limit of uniformly continuous and continuous functions are equal implies both are uniformly continuous

Tags: limits, continuity, uniform-continuity

Given $f:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R} $ a uniformly continuous function and   $g:[0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R} $ a continuous function.
If $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x) - f(x) = 0$$ is g uniformly continuous over $[0, \infty)$? Thank you for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you considered the case $f\equiv 0$?

Comment: What is the argument $i$ in your limit?

Comment: Thank you, that was meant to be an x

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE. Is it meant to be "$x \to \infty$"?

Comment: As Severin says, you should consider $f = 0$ first. This is discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/705961/473276).

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $g-f$ is uniformly continuous as $g-f$ is continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}g(x)-f(x)=0$. Since $f$ and $g-f$ are uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$, $g=(g-f)+f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,\infty)$.